# What is the highest quality graduated neutral density filter?

Tags: filters, lee, graduated-filters

I've been trying to find a Lee .9 Hard stop GND since November.  Really, November of '09.  Adorama, b&h, amazon were all out.  I finally found one on amazon through a third party in the beginning of July.  This led to me to think that going the Lee route was not the best idea.

So my question - what is the highest quality GND out there?  I will be using it for landscapes, and don't mind a system.  I heard that Cokin casts a ruby tint in their GND, so I avoided them.  I do not want a threaded, spin GND, as I need to adjust the horizon, without changing the composition.

Thanks

Comment: I'd love to see how the (very expensive) Singh-Ray Vari-ND Filters compare. They sure sound a lot more practical and better than all fixed ND filters.

Comment: Oops, sorry, Vari-ND ist not graduated, so can't be compared for your uses.

Comment: http://www.kenrockwell.com/tech/grads.htm

Answer (score 7):

I recently purchased some Lee ND and ND grad filters. I had a tough time finding them online, and finally searched around locally for a store that sold them. Best I can tell, Lee filters are not much of an online commodity, and are sold in retail stores most of the time. I do believe that Lee makes some of highest (if not the highest) quality filters available, and if you can find a local store, they are definitely worth it.

Here is a PDF that might be helpful:

[Lee Camera Dealers](http://www.leefiltersusa.com/downloads/LEECameraDealers.pdf)

UPDATE:

The story on Lee filters is a much more complex one than I originally noted above. I seem to have been lucky finding anything, particularly the foundation kit, locally. There isn't a single local store near where I live anymore that has any Lee filter equipment. I've turned to online sources, but they are nearly as dry. I managed to get a .3, .6, and .9 Soft GND set from B&H, and have found some filter adapter rings on Adorama. Generally speaking though, the most disappointing thing about Lee filters is the simple fact that they are not available...ANYWHERE. I've been on a waiting list for some filter slide guides and extension screws for my lee foundation kit for months now, with no hope in sight of actually getting any of them. I've been waiting to get some additional solid ND filters, but they also seem to be completely dry, with no date in sight for when they may be available.

There seems to be a couple online stores in the UK that have all Lee parts, but the cost is considerably higher than the already high cost here in the US, not counting any import fees. Very sad state of affairs with Lee filter equipment. There is no question Lee makes the best filters around, but without any of it being available for general purchase, their amazing quality is kind of moot. Perhaps an online petition to Lee to step up production and fill their supply lines would be useful.

Comment: How did the prices compare to the out of stock prices online?

Comment: @reuscam: If I remember correctly, they were a little more. I think I found the filter holder kit online for about $75, but it was about $85 in the store. I don't remember the prices being dramatically different, but they were a little higher across the board, sadly. If you find an online store that sells them, PLEASE, let us know! :D

Comment: This is what I snagged the other day after months of searching, although I'm not sure the price beats any local places: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00009R7WG/ref=oss_product

Comment: Seems about right ($119). If you are only buying one, the difference might not be much. If you want to buy a bunch, buying online might save you a decent amount.