# How can I take slow, wide-open photos in bright light?

Tags: exposure, tips, sports, neutral-density, overexposure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are neutral density filters and how do I use them to create long exposures in daylight?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15242/what-are-neutral-density-filters-and-how-do-i-use-them-to-create-long-exposures)

I like to take photos of motorsports and high speed action. Sometimes I use really fast shots, like 1/4000s, but sometimes I like to take a slower shot to get some 'movement' - say 1/500s or slower. It helps when a car is sliding through a corner, for example!

At the same time I like to use a big aperture to achieve shallow depth of field to really make the subject stand out. Especially if I'm trying to capture some motion, I don't want the subject to have some motion blur and the background appear relatively sharper. So I often have the aperture open to 3.5 or 2.8; I'd like to have the option to open it even more.

The sun is often very bright here, so I find that slower shutter speed and higher aperture lead to over exposed images. The camera is on ISO 100 but it's still too bright!

So my question is how can I achieve the motion blur and shallow depth of field that I'm after in bright conditions, without being overexposed?

Comment: Hey Kirk, great question and thanks for asking it. We try to keep the site clean by closing posts that are duplicate of others, and it looks like this is a duplicate of one. So don't worry if it gets closed as a duplicate! Also, since you didn't know that the name was "neutral density" it would have been very hard for you to find the duplicate! See our FAQ for more info: http://photo.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: @dpollitt cheers :) I'm familiar with the SE format (longtime SO user) but I don't know much about photography! Feel free to close as duplicate.