# Which filter would I use for daytime lightning long exposure?

Tags: long-exposure, neutral-density, lightning

I'm new to the photography scene and although I managed to take a reasonable night time lightning strike on long exposure, during the daytime, I can't seem to get it right (too bright) and a friend told me to use an ND Filter. Is this something to consider and what type as my research led me to so many different types.

I am using a Canon 600D with the 18-55mm kit lens.

Comment: See http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15242/what-are-neutral-density-filters-and-how-do-i-use-them-to-create-long-exposures.

Answer (score 2):

The differences between ND filters are not necessarily between *kinds* but rather between *values*.

The value you should look for is how many f-stops (or in this case shutter speeds) do you want to change.

Let's say the light conditions you are taking the photo in now (9AM, with sunlight, in summer, your iso and aperture well defined) give you a shutter speed of 1/500 and you need a exposure of 1/2 second.

The f-stop difference will be

```
1/250=1

1/125=2

 1/60=3

 1/30=4

 1/15=5

  1/8=6

  1/4=7

  1/2=8
```

So you need a filter that reduces the light 8 f-stops.

According to this table http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_density_filter you can use a ND108 or N119 filter.

It is not recommended that you stalk too many filters, but probably 2 will be fine, so you can buy for example a 103 and a 106 and combine them to have a 109.

Polarizing filters are helpful and they have an Xx scale to see the f-stop change. A filter that is marked 2x will reduce the f-stop 2 steps.